# Android emulator for android 11 is saving pictures and videos in a different location compared to previous versions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-11

I have a backup app that searches for photos and videos inside sdcard/DCIM and takes backup. Testing it on Android emulator for Android 11. Since android 11 it's saving the pictures and video taken through emulator inside sdcard/Pictures and sdcard/Movies which a new behavior. My app is not able to back it up now. I tried looking for any documentation which suggested this change in android 11 but couldn't find any. Can any of you help me with this if this is the desired behavior going forward?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#external
I guess it might be helpful.

`To give users more control over their files and to limit file clutter, apps that target Android 10 (API level 29) and higher are given scoped access into external storage, or scoped storage, by default. When scoped storage is enabled, apps cannot access the app-specific directories that belong to other apps.`


Also, there are few changes in storage in Android 11:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Comment: You did not tell where this backup app used to store the backup. Please tell full path. `My app is not able to back it up now.` Is that a different app or the backup app you are talking about?

Comment: `it's saving the pictures and video taken through emulator inside sdcard/Pictures and sdcard/Movies ` Unclear. Who is `it's`? Your backup app or the Camera app or which app?

Comment: The emulator is not saving anything. Apps do. Please reformulate subject and post to tell what is going on.

Comment: The default Camera app on an Android 11 emulator saves it pictures in /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera. So i do not understand where you are talking about.